# Logstash pattern dealing with multiple matches

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

Facing very much difficulty to extract in grok

```
hi i am good [anything] hey [another] hii [third] kjkj [fourth]  etc
```

in the above string how can i extract [anything] to one field
have used `(^.+)(?<thread_name>\[.+\])` but it extracts last match

Answer (score 1):

```
(^[^\[]+)(?<thread_name>\[[^\]]+\])
```

This one is modified yours. It will work to extract exactly first match of a word in square brackets. Please provide more details if you need a more tuned pattern.

Output will be:

```
{
  "thread_name": [
    [
      "[anything]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I recommend using the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) for quick checking grok patterns.

Comment: Thanks if [anything] like  not there in input then thread_name field should be created with empty value

Comment: Facing   _grokparsefailure if no [dfd] is there